# Directs sum of subspaces dimension theorem problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Given V finite dimensional vector space and W, W1, W2 subspaces of V.

W1 ∩ W2 = {0}.

V=W+W1=W+W2.

dimV=2dimW.

Prove that V=W⊕W1=W⊕W2=W1⊕W2

Tried a lot of ways, but I can't get to stage I prove that dimW=dimW1=dimW2 or that W ∩ W1 = {0} and W ∩ W2 = {0} needed for direct sum conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help.